# Slowed meaning negative or just in this sentences

Tags: british-english

In this paragraph:

> For the €362bn personal luxury goods sector, 2023 may go down as the
> year that the post-Covid bubble finally burst.
>
> Despite the reopening of China at the start of the year, demand for
> personal luxury products slowed to 8 per cent at constant currency
> rates according to Bain, narrowly outpacing global inflation and
> marking a significant deceleration after three consecutive years of 20
> per cent sales growth on average. Investors took note: for the first
> time in seven years, luxury stocks did not outperform the broader
> equity market.

what's the meaning of

> *demand for personal luxury products slowed to 8 per cent at constant currency
> rates according to Bain*

Negative 8 percent  or just 8 percent less than other years?

Comment: No tricky wording here. After three consecutive years of 20% **growth**, demand slowed to 8% growth. Not -8%, but 8% up for total annual demand. Say, 20%, 20%, 20%, 8%, and maybe 6% next year. The percentages are not calculated on each other.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Now this question will never be answered.

Comment: @tchrist: The question shouldn't be here on the first place. Obviously only ***learners*** (not *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*) would need an explanation of the difference between *slowed **to** 8 per cent* and *slowed **by** 8 per cent*, which seems to be the only real question here.

Comment: @tchrist Forgive me, please, we have a difference of opinion. I agree with FumbleFingers that this question does not belong. But out of what I see as neighborly before the question goes, I offer a simple analysis. There is no "answer" suited to the question of unnuanced language that is a misunderstanding of math.

Comment: It's no different from something like "The car slowed to 10 KPH." Would you think that meant they were going backwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It previously had been growing at 20% per year. But in 2023 it grew at only 8%.  That is still 8% growth, but not as much growth as there had been in previous years.

This is not a particular nuance of English, and similar expressions can be found in other languages.  By way of analogy if one said "The car slowed to 8 km/h" it doesn't mean it is going backwards.